# Localization selenium framework

Tags: selenium, automation, localization, frameworks, testng

I am working project where application support multi-language (Apart from English) lets say German,Spanish ,French etc

So I want design TestNG+Page Object Model Selenium Framework so that it can support muli-language.

Framework should have feature to select language ,based on selection UI language should get change.

For example :

In English UI ,have save  button, we want to click ,then we can write code as below:
//button[contains(text(),'Save')]

But once we change(French) language then
//button[contains(text(),'Enregistrer')]

can some one please help me for framework.

Comment: Good question. Upvoating it but I am not sure there is the way to implement that with POM since Selenium native POM support involves annotation mechanisms which does not allow to evaluate annotation values in runtime.

Comment: I still believe this can be design,let me share my though :Lets say there is base class (TestNG) where all function written like open URL and check other functionality like clicking other button  ,but actual function of clicking button will be maintain in page model ,so if we say clicking Save button , x-path and logic will be define in Page Class.Now we can not hardecoded path here since example I given once we switch language string which I want to use in code will different,so we need to externalize.

Comment: You can check my answer where I give the example of solution. If you want to use `PageFactory` way, you have to deal with it. On the other hand, Page Object is just a pattern. You are free to implement it on your own, not necessary to use `PageFactory`. For example you can describe methods of the objects which would use classic approach with `driver.findElement(...)` where you will be building your xpath dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. It is possible. Despite you cannot evaluate annotations in run-time you still can break into the logic that takes the place when the annotation value is being processed.

What you need to do is:

1. Create custom annotation that would be processed with custom implementation of `AbstractFindByBuilder`
2. Implement that extension of `AbstractFindByBuilder` that would recognize parameters in locator and replaces them with the values

Sounds easy but still needs some level of coding. Here you can see the example of [parameterizing `FindBy` annotations for Selenium page object](https://webelement.click/en/parameterized_findby_annotation_in_selenium_page_object_java).